# Unrecognized characters in a genereted index of a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04, charset

I have some files on a server with non-ASCII names and when I'm browswing the apache-generated index of a directory, the non-ASCII characters are not recognized (shown as ?).

I've added instructions in the .htaccess files :

```
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
```

I've set the default charset in apache2 conf file :

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

and in my directory clause, I have :

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes
```

and it's still not working, any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the filenames on your server are encoded as UTF-8?

If you have older files and live in europe (as I) it is
very likely your filenames are encoded in ISO8859-1 (sometimes also called latin-1) or ISO8859-15.  Debian (and so Ubuntu) used to contain a package
called:

```
utf8-migration-tool
```

which contains a wizard like utility to convert filenames.
This tool is written in scripting language Python.  It contains a module named:

```
/usr/share/utf8-migration-tool/pylib/wizard/steps.py
```

which in turn contains a class called

```
FileNameConversion
```

Unfortunately this class will need to be refactored to be
usefull to manipulate filenames in a certain part of your
filesystem.  May be you want change your Apache configuration
to ISO8859-1 for a short test first?